# Construction of the free product of $C^*$-algebras

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

[image]

The content of the screenshot is from Pisier's book.

I have two questions ：

1. $\mathcal{F}$ is an algebra, how to conclude that $\pi: \mathcal{F} \to B(H_{\pi})$ is a $*$-homomorphism?

2.Why is $j$ injective?